# Is it possible for Javascript to duplicate an element in the DOM?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

I have a pulldown menu created from PHP querying a database and then using `foreach` loop creating a list of options for that pull down menu.

However in my form users may require to enter more of the same fields so I was wondering is it possible to make JavaScript copy an element like a pulldown with all its values and then place duplicate it in the same form?

Why I am thinking like this, because I can't seem to find a way to pass a PHP array to JavaScript or at least I can't find a way to do it :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't remember the plain javascript way, with jQuery you can use the [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method, however I'd not use this approach because you'll get same post names. Better to do this in php unless you need a dynamic form. In that case clone is the solution, but keep an eye on input names when doing that.

Comment: The plain way is `element.cloneNode()`. Not hard. :-)

Comment: I've downvoted this question because as of 2011 this answer shouldn't be one that is considered canonical.

Answer (score 5):

Please, don't use jQuery for this! jQuery is great, but there is no point in including the whole library for something as simple as this. Unless you already use jQuery, you should go with Javascript's cloneNode() function. Of course you can also use Ajax to communicate with PHP, but "just" Javascript is both faster and easier.

Comment: I was going to post my own answer, but yours is pretty much the same approach. So, if you'll permit, I'll offer a [JS Fiddle demo, using `cloneNode()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7Sd4W/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using the DOM methods, but better yet, use jQuery and look at the `clone` method: http://api.jquery.com/clone/.

You could pass a PHP array to Javascript by serializing it to a JSON object, but that's another story.

Comment: Not that you're wrong, but 'better yet'?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like

```
<select name="top5" size="5" multiple="">
  <option>Heino</option>
  <option>Michael Jackson</option>
  <option>Tom Waits</option>
  <option>Nina Hagen</option>
  <option>Marianne Rosenberg</option>
</select>
```

This allows you to select multiple options ([enter link description here](http://de.selfhtml.org/html/formulare/anzeige/select_multiple.htm))

Comment: Yes I mean something like that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass a php-array to javascript, you could actually do the following:

```
var php_array = eval('(' + <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?> + ')');
```