# How to duplicate a div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how I can duplicate a `DIV` element a few times through JavaScript without duplicating the DIV in my html code?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, try `.clone()`. On usage, I'll leave it to you to read it up yourself.

Comment: [jquery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: I don't get all the downvotes - this is a legitimate question that is not a duplicate. The DOM API can be hard to navigate and the user is new. The question is short and clear. This can seem very offensive to a new user. Worse, I don't get the two suggestions above me to include over 10K lines of code in order to perform a method all browsers support out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542758/dynamically-duplicate-html-div-with-javascript

Comment: @geedubb Nice find! Couldn't find it before. I'm voting to mark the other one as a duplicate of this since the other one is very badly asked imo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible for Javascript to duplicate an element in the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851399/is-it-possible-for-javascript-to-duplicate-an-element-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 42):

Let's assume the you selected the div doing something like:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivId");
```

The DOM API contains a [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) method which you can use

```
var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true); // the true is for deep cloning
```

Now you can add it to the document

```
document.body.appendChild(divClone);
```

Here is a [short self contained code example illustrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/rzMB3/)

Comment: +10 for not suggesting using jQuery for three lines of vanilla JS

Comment: and how can i duplicate it like 10 times?

Comment: @utopy You can repeat the action as many times as you'd like (just be sure to change the `.id` property of divClone so it won't lead to multiple IDs. If you're looking for a language construct in JavaScript that lets you repeat actions multiple times without actually writing them multiple times - check out `for` and `while` loops. Check out the [basic examples section in this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: I don't see what's so bad about suggesting jQuery. If the user is new to javascript it's worth making them aware of this excellent framework. They may never have heard of it before.

Comment: @geedubb Several things. First, Please consider reading about what a framework is (hint: jQuery is not a framework). Second, [many reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/) otherwise we'll end up [here](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif). Lack of understanding of how the DOM API works, or what it is makes for some pretty bad programmers. You use libraries on top of foundations - first learn the language and APIs and then learn abstractions. You don't want to encourage bad practices and poor code. You want to encourage actual understanding.

Comment: @geedubb I was not patronizing, you misused a term so I pointed you to the right direction...  I apologize if that came off as rude that was not my intention. I was just "being clever" ;)