# How to avoid generated duplicade html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe this is a common question in javascript world, but i can't find any usefull keyword for a profitable search. Long story short:

I have html code generated server side, suppose something like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element">
        <!-- yadayada -->
    </div>

    <div class="element">
        <!-- yadayada -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and a client script to add new elements without reloading the page

```
<script>
    // do asynchronous server stuff, then add new div from json server output
    var string = "<div class=\"element\">\n" +
                 "    <!-- yadayada -->\n" +
                 "</div>";
    $("#container").prepend($(string));
</script>
```

Well, if the `<!-- yadayada -->` internal layout is changed in the server scripts, the javascript code must also be changed.

How can I avoid this ? how can I have only one maintainable source for the yadayada layout ?

Comment: just use jQueries `.clone()` method to copy one that the server made rather than hard coding from the beginning

Comment: I think GBWDev should convert the comment into an answer!  You could have an empty yadayada template that's hidden via CSS.  Also, if jQuery is not available, there is a way to do it with just JavaScript:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482091/1157037

Comment: Thank you @HarryPehkonen, I flagged the question as duplicate, your link is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can 'clone' an item served up by the server.

`elem.cloneNode(true)`

On a page that I did, I named one element 'master' and then used that to create all new elements as needed (I hid the *master* with CSS `display: none`).

As mentioned in other posts you can use `.clone()` with jquery.

If you do not want to use jQuery, you can use regular javascript:

> Excerpt from the W3 Schools site:

```
// Get the last <li> element ("Milk") of <ul> with id="myList2"
var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;
// Copy the <li> element and its child nodes
var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
// Append the cloned <li> element to <ul> with id="myList1"
document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
```

The above is an example of cloning in regular javascript from W3 Schools site: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Answer (score 2):

Clone the first of the elements and prepend it to the container like so:

```js
$('.element:first').clone().prependTo('#container');
```